# Generate javascript variable names in Razor foreach block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach

I want to generate javascript variable names in a foreach block in my view.  So far I have something like this:

```
        @foreach (var layer in Model.Layers)
        {
            @:var @layer.Name = new FeatureLayer("@layer.Url", {
                @:mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                @:outFields: ["*"]
            @:});

            @:map.addLayer(@layer.Name);
        }
```

which appears to render and work correctly (there is another issue that is blocking my ability to fully test it).  Is this the right way to go about generating js variable names in a foreach loop?  It just looks ugly to me and the editor underlines (red squiggle) the '=' sign.

Comment: Rather than have `@:` in each line, why not just wrap the JavaScript portion with `<text>JavaScript</text>`. A bit cleaner.

Comment: I have seen that convention.  It does make sense for multi-line statements.